# use of many to many and one to many relationships between 3 models at the same time

Tags: django

I know how to do one-to-many and many-to-many relationships with Django, but I'm particularly stuck here. I have three tables (pattern, document, folder), the pattern and document tables are linked by a many to many relationship, and the pattern and folder tables are linked by a one ton many relationship. I want that by implementing a pattern in the folders, all documents that are linked to it appear in the folders

```
class Motif(models.Model):
    m_designation=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    document=models.ManyToManyField(Document)
    create_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.m_designation
```

```
# Create your models here.

class Dossier(models.Model):
    
    statut=(('Valider en Agance','Valider en Agance'),
            ('Valider controle BEAC','Valider controle BEAC'),
            ('Rejeter Controleur BEAC','Rejeter Controleur BEAC')
            )
    devise=(('Euro','EUR'),
            ('Dollar Americain', 'USD'),
            ('YEN','JPY'),   
            ('MAD','MAD')
            )
    agence=models.ForeignKey(Agence,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    raison_sociale=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Numero_de_Compte=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    motif=models.ForeignKey(Motif,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    devise=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=devise,default='EUR')
    cours=models.FloatField(default=650)
    mt_devise=models.FloatField()
    beneficiaire=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    statut=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=statut,default='Valider en Agance')
    create_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
    def  mt_xaf(self,):
            return int (self.mt_devise * self.cours)
```

```
# Create your models here.

class Document(models.Model):
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    create_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.designation
```

Comment: Please use english in names of fields and models, or at least translate code before posting. What if chinese guy would name their model like "文件夾", and ask you for help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you have

```py
class Pattern:
    documents = Many2Many(Document)

class Folder:
    pattern = ForeignKey(Pattern)

class Document:
    ...
```

Then you can retrieve all documents from the folder like below:

```py
folder.pattern.documents.all()
```

Comment: I put it in the view or the model folder?